# Create columns with upper and lower borders obtained from list

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame and a list of borders:

```py
test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1,),
        (2,),
        (234,),
        (0,),
        (6,),
        (7,),
        (35,),
        (46,),
        (8,),
    ],  
    "Population int",
)

border_list = [0, 1.5, 7, 41, 235]
```

And I want to add two new columns to the DataFrame ("LowerBorder", "UpperBorder") for the "Population" column.

And when I tried it to do with just python list and functions, it worked:

```py
lower = lambda x: max([i for i in border_list if x >= i])
upper = lambda x: min([i for i in border_list if x < i])

list_value = [1, 2, 234, 0, 6, 7, 35, 46, 8]

for i in list_value:
    print(lower(i), upper(I))

# Output:
# low  high
  0    1.5
  1.5  7
  41   235
  0    1.5
  1.5  7
  7    41
  7    41
  41   235
  7    41
```

But when I have tried to convert it to work with a column, it hasn't:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
lower_border = F.udf(lambda x: max([i for i in border_list if x >= i]), FloatType())
upper_border = F.udf(lambda x: min([i for i in border_list if x < i]), FloatType())

test.withColumn("LowBorder", lower_border("Population")) \
    .withColumn("UpBorder", upper_border("Population"))

display(test) # no changes in test Dataframe
```

If I try to add columns through select, it also doesn't work as desired:

```py
display(test.select(lower_border("Population").alias('low'), upper_border("Population").alias('high')))

# Output:
low    high
-----------
null    1.5
1.5     null
null    null
null    1.5
1.5     null
null    null
null    null
null    null
null    null
```

Expected output for test DataFrame is:

```
Population | LowBorder | UpBorder
---------------------------------
1            0           1.5
2            1.5         7
234          41          235
0            0           1.5
6            1.5         7
7            7           41
35           7           41
46           41          235
8            7           41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array out of your `border_list`, then [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html#pyspark.sql.functions.filter) it and select either minimum or maximum.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
test = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (234,), (0,), (6,), (7,), (35,), (46,), (8,)], "Population int")
border_list = [0, 1.5, 7, 41, 235]

arr = F.array_sort(F.array([F.lit(x) for x in border_list]))
test = test.select(
    'Population',
    F.element_at(F.filter(arr, lambda x: x <= F.col('Population')), -1).alias('LowBorder'),
    F.element_at(F.filter(arr, lambda x: x > F.col('Population')), 1).alias('UpBorder'),
)
test.show(truncate=0)
# +----------+---------+--------+
# |Population|LowBorder|UpBorder|
# +----------+---------+--------+
# |1         |0.0      |1.5     |
# |2         |1.5      |7.0     |
# |234       |41.0     |235.0   |
# |0         |0.0      |1.5     |
# |6         |1.5      |7.0     |
# |7         |7.0      |41.0    |
# |35        |7.0      |41.0    |
# |46        |41.0     |235.0   |
# |8         |7.0      |41.0    |
# +----------+---------+--------+
```